How to reliably measure user analytics on GitHub Pages site?
My static site is on GitHub Pages. And my audience is very tech-savvy, so rather likely to be using AdBlock, uBlock, NoScript, etc.
GitHub Pages does not provide any kind of web traffic information. And Google Analytics, I believe, won't work with AdBlock.
Is there any other way to reliably see how many people visit my site, from which countries, etc.? Perhaps some image host that allows embedding and provides traffic info?

One option, if you're using a custom domain, is to proxy your domain through Cloudflare. They provide built-in server-side analytics.

@MaximillianLaumeister I'm using a custom domain with a GitHub-provided certificate.

Then Cloudflare would definitely be a viable solution, if you don’t mind that all your traffic would be routed through them.

What Maximillian suggested with using CF to host your DNS records and thus collect some stats on requests is a very elegant and simple solution. I just checked my CF dashboard and here is how it looks:

It has all the top level metrics it seems like. Simple yet useful. And all you need to do is host to your DNS records with CF. And no adblockers or privacy thingies can do anything to it.
Alternatively, bypassing adblockers for regular front-end analytics is a tough and somewhat expensive thing to do. It would involve having a local mirror redirecting the tracking requests to the tracker's endpoint.
